# How to refresh an HTML form to capture a previous value

Tags: php, html, forms, laravel-5

Hopefully I can make this clear.

So I have a form that will ask you to choose a single option from a number of radio boxes, a category.  Like this.  The (x) will be the radio image.

(1) cata (2) catb (3) catc ...

When the user selects one of the three options above I then need to know which one they selected So I can then display another set of radio items for the sub categories within the above category.

(1) subcat (2) subcat (3) subcat ...

I suppose what I need to do is do a interim refresh/submit of the form so it captures the value of the first selection so I can identify the category id and then use it to pull through the sub categories.

Hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% percent sure on your requirements. But you can use HTML5 Local Storage to remember form information.

http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

```
//Get the value
var rad1 = localStorage.getItem("rad1");

//Set the value
localStorage.setItem("rad1", rad1);
```

Comment: Thanks, will have a look at that.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. Local storage is great.